# How make string of all values of particular data table column in asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am using asp.net 2.0. I have a data table which contains int_TASK_ID as one of its column. I want to create string of all task IDs from data table rows without using loop on data table rows. Is there any way in asp.net 2.0?

Comment: Not possible in `2.0` without loops, this can be done using `Linq`, for that you'll be required `Asp.net 3.5`...

Comment: What is the reason for not having loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. To achieve it without loops, you may need a query language. So you can do it with SQL but as you said you already have a data table, so NO. If it would be in .net 4.0, you could have done that with Linq.

In .net 2.0 without loops you can directly get string of all IDs from db itself by writing concat query to your db.